# Unable to properly embed video in Leaflet popup marker

Tags: javascript, video, leaflet

I've been working on a Leaflet map recently, and after putting in a popup marker on the map, I have been unable to properly embed a mp4 video in that marker.

The issue is that while I have embedded the link to the video in the marker, the video won't play when you open the popup marker; it just shows a frozen image. I was wondering if there was a workaround to get the video to play in this popup marker automatically once the popup is opened.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css"
    integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A=="
    crossorigin=""/>
 
    <style>
        #map { height: 800px; }
    </style>


</head>
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>

 

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"
    integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA=="
    crossorigin=""></script>
    <script>
       var map = L.map('map').setView([27.2, 84], 4);
  
       var Esri_NatGeoWorldMap = L.tileLayer('https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/NatGeo_World_Map/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}', {
        attribution: 'Tiles &copy; Esri &mdash; National Geographic, Esri, DeLorme, NAVTEQ, UNEP-WCMC, USGS, NASA, ESA, METI, NRCAN, GEBCO, NOAA, iPC',
        maxZoom: 16
        }).addTo(map);

        var marker = L.marker([27.2,83.95],{draggable: true, title:"Hello", opacity: 0.5}).addTo(map).bindPopup('<h1>Marker</h1><video> <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>').openPopup();

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Add an [`autoplay`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/autoplay) attribute to the `<video>` tag. Additionally add the [`controls`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/controls) attribute to allow playing and pausing of the video.